# mysql over ssh over non-standard port

Tags: mysql, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am on computer A, and have mysql running on it, and can connect to it as `A~ $ mysql -u punkish -p database` and so on.

I have access to computer B that also has mysql running on it. I can ssh into B over port 2200 with ssh key pairs set up, and once in, I can connect to the db like so

```
A~ $ ssh -p 2200 punkish@B
B~ $ mysql -u punkish -p database
```

However, I want to set up port forwarding over ssh on my computer so all requests made for mysql on port 3307 on my computer A are actually sent to port 3306 on B. This will allow me to use a gui program that wants to connect to mysql, but can't do it over a tunnel. So, I do the following

```
A~ $ ssh -p 2200 -L 3307:B:3306 punkish@B
B~ $
```

The above logs me right into B. I am not sure if the tunnel is established, but I am assuming it is. However, the following fails (in another terminal

```
A~ $ mysql -P 3307 -u punkish -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'punkish'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Here is the interesting thing -- I have another gui program called Sequel Pro (a desktop MySQL client for Mac OS X), and that is able to make a connection to mysql@B over ssh just fine. So, I know something works... I just don't know how, so I may be able to enable it for another gui program.

Comment: Perhaps this would be better suited for superuser ( http://superuser.com/ ) ?

Answer (score 2):

mysql usually attempts to use a socket file if you don't specify a hostname. So as part of your mysql command, specify `-h 127.0.0.1` (notice I did NOT say localhost, it treats them differently). This basically forces a TCP connection instead of the socket file connection.

Comment: ok. I actually had tried that and failed, but tried it again anyway. I get a different error like so `A ~$mysql -P 3307 -p -h 127.0.0.1 -u punkish
Enter password: 
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0`

Comment: No idea. Since I don't know anything about your tunnel setup, this is the best I can offer. Try running `nmap -Pn -p3307 localhost` to make sure that the port is actually listening correctly.

Comment: I am on Mac OS X, and as far as I can tell, there is no `nmap` on it.

Comment: @punkish: yes you'll need to install it. I can't help with that, I don't have any experience with OS X. nmap simply connects to the specified port and reports whether or not it's responsive. There may be other programs to do this (port scanning) under OS X.